# wprintf accepting "wchar_t" ptr from function

Tags: c

From inside main, I tried to call ParseInput that returns a wide-character pointer to a string, which I'd like to wprintf to console. So far, 
the code compiles, but wprintf does nothing when called. Something simple, right ? (But I still can't see it)

```
wchar_t *ParseInput(wchar_t *arg)
{
    wchar_t str[32];

    if (arg == L"option_1")
    {
        wcscpy_s(str, L"ret_1");
    }
    else
    if (arg == L"option_2")
    {
        wcscpy_s(str, L"ret_2");
    }

    return str;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    wchar_t *wstr;

    wstr = ParseInput(L"option_1");

    wprintf(L"%ls\n", wstr); 

    return 0;
}
```

best,
Chris

Comment: Local variables are destroyed at the end of their scope. That includes `str` in `ParseInput`.

Comment: besides that: comparing strings with `==` doesn't work as you might expect. This is true for "normal" strings as well as for wide strings. Look up `wscmp()`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you don't use `wcscmp()` in

```
if (arg == L"option_1")
    {
        wcscpy_s(str, L"ret_1");
    }
```

?

```
if (!wcscmp(arg, L"option_1"))
    {
        wcscpy_s(str, L"ret_1");
    }
```

Comment: A valid criticism of the code, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you Konstantin; definitely a will-do !